# How can I use float nub and words in input at the same time?

Tags: python

```
cheese = float(input("Enter cheese order weight (numeric value): "))

if cheese >= 100:
    print(cheese,"is more than currently available stock ")
elif cheese <= 0.15:
    print(cheese,"is below minimum order amount")
elif cheese >= 0.16 <= 99:
    print(cheese," costs $",cheese * 7.99,sep = "")
else:
    print(cheese,"Is invlide, please try agin")
```

Every time I add a letter I get an error. I want to be able to add float nub and words, so I can use the else statement.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Your code has many issues - for example, what about amounts like 0.155 or 99.5 cheese? Apart from that, if you enter anything that's not a valid `float`, your first line will fail. If only there was a way to `try` it and use it `except` when there's a problem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what *"nub"* means? But you need to put this in a loop and handle the errors using `try` and `except`:

```
cheese_weight = None
# Repeat until there is a valid value for cheese_weight
while not cheese_weight:
    # Step 1: get some user input
    raw_input = input("Enter cheese order weight (numeric value): ")
    # Step 2: try convert this input to a float
    try:
        cheese_weight = float(raw_input)
    # Step 3: handle the error if there is one
    except ValueError as err:
        print("The cheese weight must be a numeric value.)
```

note that if `float(raw_input)` raises an error, `cheese_weight` won't get a new value and so the loop will run again. If the value does parse as a float, then `cheese_weight` will have a value that isn't `None` and so the loop will end.